# Gradle build is too slow

Tags: performance, android-studio, build, gradle

for example if I changed small code I will get this result in gradle console x

```
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iy$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jl$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/os.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ke$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jt$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jv$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ju$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/li.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ih$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jl$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/op.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/r$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ke$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$h.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/js.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/j.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kv$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/oq$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/oq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/o.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ox.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iy$2.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/r.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$i.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/la.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jl$f.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ra$d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/i$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ig.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/p.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jr$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kf$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ld.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iz$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ko.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ji.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/s$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$f.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jn$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$i.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/n.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iy$3.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jl$h.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ra$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ke.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ju.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jm$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/oq$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ko$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/j$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jq$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kh$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$j.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/q.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$k.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/js$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kh$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jn$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jl$e.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/g.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iz$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ra$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$g.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/os$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jm$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$e.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kc$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jt$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/d$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/je.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kv$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ra.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iy$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ky.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/pu$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ra$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iy$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/m.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kr$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/hb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iz$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ki.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/oo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$h.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/l.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/pu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$j.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/r$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ka.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ks.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/s$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/h.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/i.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ki$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$l.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jl$d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/f$f.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jb$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/s.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/km.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/kr$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/lk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/qp$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/ju$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/o$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jc$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/c$e.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/iy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/e.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/f.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$3.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$5.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$4.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$7.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/c$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/g.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$6.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/d$a$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/d$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/c$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/g$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/h.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/a$2.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamic/c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ExceptionParser.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/k.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ad.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$2.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ac.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/h$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/CampaignTrackingReceiver.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/StandardExceptionParser.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/e.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/Logger.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders$HitBuilder.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/c$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/f.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/aa.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders$ExceptionBuilder.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/n$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/z$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders$SocialBuilder.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/j.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/y.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/o.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders$EventBuilder.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/v$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/r.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ai.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/y$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/x$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/p.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/Logger$LogLevel.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ExceptionReporter.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/x$d.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/TrackerHandler.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/al.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/n.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/z.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/u.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/k$1.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/c$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/q.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/t.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/CampaignTrackingService.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ag$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ak.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/x$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/g.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/v$2.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/x$b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders$TimingBuilder.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ab.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/af.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/aj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/am.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/b.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/x$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/ae.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/v.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/m.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/c$a.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$c.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/l.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/h.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/i.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/analytics/w$e.class...
```

it is normal to take 
16:03:08.530 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 3 mins 9.729 secs

These are some libraries that I use

```
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+"'
    /*compile project(':viewPagerIndicator241')*/
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    /*compile files('libs/androidannotations-api-3.2.jar')*/
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
   /* compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.2.jar')*/
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
    compile files('libs/prettytime-3.2.5.Final.jar')
```

Comment: It is slow because you are too many libraries. You application is very bloated. This is why you have to use multidex and multidex is slow. Please post your entire `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this new `build.gradle`:

I would highly recommend trying to move away from `MultiDex` as it is **very** slow.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
...

    dependencies {
        // Gradle dependencies
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'                // <-- was 1.0.1
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'             // <-- was 21+
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'                   // <-- was 2.2.4
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'   // <-- was 6.5.87
        compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' // <-- deprecated, move to AppCompat
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'                         // <-- was compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'                             // <-- was compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'          // <-- was compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
        compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime-nlp:3.2.5.Final' // <-- was files('libs/prettytime-3.2.5.Final.jar')
        // Jars
        compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    }
}
```

I'd suggest trying to remove some of these dependencies:

- Jake Whartons's `ActionBarSherlock` is `DEPRECATED`, switch to `App Compat`
- You have 2 chart libraries `achartengine` and `mpandroidchartlibrary`
- Do you really need Google's `gson` vs Android's built-in `json` libs?
- Do you really need Common's IO?