# Gradle Build is very slow

Tags: android

I am using android studio and i have updated android studio with version 141.1890965. But still my android gradle build is too slpw it take almost 3 minute when i build it for first time and then 1 min 20 sec around. I tried out many solution on google but still i am help less. Following are the links which i tried.

[Gradle build is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392713/gradle-build-is-too-slow)

[Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

[Android studio Gradle build speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up)

Comment: You're ab right. i faced too.

Comment: best (for me) is never to use maven or gradle and stick to eclipse. It is so darn fast comparing with all that stuff...

Comment: Please try to explain your question without link references.

Comment: There is a option called as offline work in Android Studio under settings->Build,execution,Development ->Buildtools -> check offline work. this could make little bit faster.

Comment: @Muthu i tried this solution but still i facing same problem

Comment: @ondermerol Before two month i was using eclipse and was not facing any time consumption while doing build but when i switched to Android studio i am facing time consuming in making build almost one and half minute every time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android studio 1.2 gradle is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024910/android-studio-1-2-gradle-is-very-slow)

Comment: @AmitCharkha How fast is your internet. because android studio normally needs a fast stable network connection. and are you using proguard?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024910/android-studio-1-2-gradle-is-very-slow/30025667#30025667)

Had the same problem.

What I did was to change the global gradle settings to offline work which can be done by going to Preferences => Gradle. This did make a difference.

Another method I have seen people use, but which I have not used yet is to create a [gradle.properties](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/) in the gradle folder like so:

Just create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

**Please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips/19500539#19500539) for more options as well as a detailed explanation on speeding up gradle.**

Hope this helps!.

Comment: i tried out both the solution but still i am facing same problem. Even i do one line change in code for build it takes almost 1 minute and 20 or 30 sec. I am facing this problem from last two months

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be dex,

turn `multiDexEnabled` to **false** in your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled false
        ...
    }
}
```

In addition you should consider to use the lastest version (2.4 at the moment) by editing the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and set gradle-**2.4**-all.zip

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```